# Purchase cache validity for Google Play Billing Library 5

Tags: android, in-app-billing, play-billing-library, google-play-billing

Does anyone know or know to find out how long a Google Play cache keeps returning purchases if there is no internet? The method call is:

```
mBillingClient.queryPurchasesAsync(SkuType.INAPP, purchaseResponseListener);
```

Current behavior if I turn off the internet:

1. Purchases are returned to onPurchasesUpdated() from what I presume is Google Play's cache
2. 20s later onBillingError() fires. EDIT: onBillingError() fires due to calling querySkuDetailsAsync(). If that isn't called along with queryPurchasesAsync(), we'd never get an error at all!

How long will a purchase be returned to onPurchasesUpdated if internet continues to be unavailable to Google Play?

Comment: I was recently working with Billing v5. I found if payment is approved late, and you have closed the app, when you reopen it, the purchase is updated automatically as soon as the Billing connection is re-established.

Comment: Sure, but that doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

I fired up an older phone that hadn't been on in a few weeks. Made sure it did not have internet at all. Google Play was still responding with the cached purchase in onPurchasesUpdated(). So it looks like **the cache is not invalidated by time passing.**

This means without any extra measures someone could make a purchase, block internet access to Google Play, cancel the order or get a refund, and continue to have the purchase indefinitely.

Comment: In other words, there is no need to make a custom cache implementation of SKU details, which I assume, was necessary for Billing 3-4?

Comment: @AkbolatSSS No I don't think it was necessary then either but my question was about the queryPurchasesAsync response cache lasting seemingly forever without internet.